# Passing an object to HTML attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc-3

How to pass an object to HTML attributes?
For example I have the following code:

```
var attrs = new { id = "myid", style = "color: Red;" };
```

How to convert attrs to string like this to embed them into an HTML markup:

```
id="myid" style="color: Red;"
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thank you for you question! I saved my day!

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This functionality is, surprisingly enough, provided by the [`RouteValueDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary.aspx) class:

```
IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary(attrs);
```

You can then use this dictionary in conjunction with a [`TagBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tagbuilder.aspx), which you will probably be using anyway:

```
var tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("input");
tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(htmlAttributes);
tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
```

You can see this done in the ASP.NET MVC source code itself; one of the simpler examples is in [TextAreaExtensions.cs](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/1ccfcdfc11da19a88f6efc6f512e67b68fa04fec/src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/TextAreaExtensions.cs#L158-L191).

**EDIT:**

In order to properly convert "data_attr" to "data-attr", use the `AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes` static method.

```
IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(attrs);
```

Comment: Just tries this with the attribute data_bind and the output was data_bind as opposed to the expected, data-bind - any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately Url to TextAreaExtensions is no longer valid :) Just letting you know.

Comment: There's an alternative, System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(), that may be more appropriate; it replaces underscores with hyphens in the same manner as the standard MVC Html helpers

Comment: This answer is obsolete. The correct approach should be `HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes)` which will properly handle `data_blah` type attributes.

Answer (score 24):

You do not need to convert to a string.  The last paramater for HTML Helpers is an Object.
You just give it the object like you have written above:

For exmample

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Foo, new { size = 10, maxlength = 10 }) 
@Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Notes, new { @class = "additionalInfo" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.Registration.Address.Postcode, new {type="number", @class="postcode numeric", size=5, maxlength=5})
```

on a side note you probably should not be setting styles directy inline with your HTML and use a CSS class/selector instead with a seperate style sheet.
Also the ID of each DOM element should automatically be set when you use MVC HTML helpers

Comment: I know, but in addition, i want to write my own method to render another form component, so i need a way to do it like MVC 3 did :)

Comment: np you problably should of mentioned that in your question

Answer (score 6):

Here's how to do this conversion :

```
var htmlAttributes = new { id="myid", @class="myclass" };

string string_htmlAttributes = "";
foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(htmlAttributes))
{
  string_htmlAttributes += string.Format("{0}=\"{1}\" ", property.Name.Replace('_', '-'), property.GetValue(htmlAttributes));
}
```

`PropertyDescriptor` belong to the class `System.ComponentModel`

Comment: No idea why this isn't the recommended answer.

Comment: the code is ok with an important change: use HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode to render the attribute value.

Comment: also  convert tag names x_y in x-y. This is how TagBuilder does it.