# IDictionary to string

Tags: c#, extension-methods, idictionary

I have created an `IDictionary` extension to write `IDictionary Exception.Data` values to a string.

The extension code:

```
public static class DictionaryExtension
{
    public static string ToString<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> source, string keyValueSeparator, string sequenceSeparator)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Parameter source can not be null.");

        return source.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, x) => sb.Append(x.Key + keyValueSeparator + x.Value + sequenceSeparator), sb => sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - 1));           
    }
}
```

When I use this extension on `Exception.Data.ToString("=", "|")` I get error

`The type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage.`

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The problem is probably related to the fact that `Exception.Data` is an `IDictionary`, not an `IDictionary<,>`. I'm surprised it calls the extension method at all.

Comment: @ThomSmith: It doesn't call the extension method. The **compiler error** happens on the line `Exception.Data.ToString("=", "|")`

Comment: Check this [Convert object htmlAttributes to string][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434865/passing-an-object-to-html-attributes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Exception.Data`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data.aspx) is of type `IDictionary`, not `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

You need to change your extension method to this:

```
public static string ToString(this IDictionary source, string keyValueSeparator,
                                                       string sequenceSeparator) 
{ 
    if (source == null) 
        throw new ArgumentException("Parameter source can not be null."); 

    return source.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                 .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                            (sb, x) => sb.Append(x.Key + keyValueSeparator + x.Value
                                                  + sequenceSeparator),
                            sb => sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - 1));            
}
```

Comment: Then I get the same exception on source.Aggregate

Comment: @Tomas: That's a **compiler error** you are getting, not an exception. Exceptions happen at runtime. Anyway, please see update. The important part is the `Cast<DictionaryEntry>()`.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is pointing that you are missing a cast. 
I copied your code in a test project but I was unable to reproduce your error. 
Try using `x.Key.ToString()` and `x.Value.ToString()`.
The only thing I found is an error raised when Dictionary is empty:
 `sb.ToString(0, sb.Length - 1)` when lenght is zero is not working