# Get all entries from an IDictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have an `IDictionary` (no not a `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`) and want to get the keys and values from it.

*In the end I would like to have keys and values as a string like `key1=value1;key2=value2;...` but at first I need to cast those pairs correctly.*

I already tried a few solutions like [IDictionary to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12197089/idictionary-to-string), but none of them worked for a `IDictionary`.

The dictionary I'm trying to read is the [`Exception.Data`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.exception.data) dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

**Using a foreach loop on IDictionary instance to create the expected string**

IDictionary has Keys and Values properties but you can achieve your goal like with this extension method using the `GetEnumerator` that returns a `DictionaryEntry`:

```
using System.Collections;

static public class IDictionaryHelper
{
  static public string ToStringFormatted(this IDictionary dictionary,
                                         char separator = ';')
  {
    string result = "";
    foreach (DictionaryEntry item in dictionary)
      result += $"{item.Key.ToString()}={item.Value.ToString()}{separator}";
    return result.TrimEnd(separator);
  }
}
```

**Test**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

IDictionary myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

myDictionary.Add("a", 1);
myDictionary.Add("b", 2);
myDictionary.Add("c", 3);

Console.WriteLine(myDictionary.ToStringFormatted());
```

[Fiddle Snippet](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8IJmR4)

**Output**

```
a=1;b=2;c=3
```

**You can use a StringBuilder if you need to parse large collections**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;

static public string ToStringFormatted(this IDictionary dictionary, char separator = ';')
{
  var builder = new StringBuilder();
  foreach ( DictionaryEntry item in dictionary )
    builder.Append($"{item.Key.ToString()}={item.Value.ToString()}{separator}");
  return builder.ToString().TrimEnd(separator);
}
```

**If you want to get lists of keys and values**

```
var keys = dictionary.Keys;
var values = dictionary.Values;

var listKeys = new List<object>();
var listValues = new List<object>();

foreach ( var item in keys )
  listKeys.Add(item);

foreach ( var item in values )
  listValues.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in (IDictionary)dictionary)
{
    sb.Append($"{entry.Key}={entry.Value};");
}

return sb.ToString();
```